# Glossary babel package

Tags: lists, acronyms

I am writing my thesis and I would like to create a list of acronyms. One option is to use is glossary package. When I used this package I ran into 2 problems.

Since my mother tongue is not English I need to use babel package. If I use it and compile my document I always get an error:

> LaTeX Error: File `tracklang.sty' not found.

I've been looking for a solution but I haven't found anything that could help me out. If I don't include babel package there is no error and compilation runs successfully but the glossary doesn't show up in my document (list of acronyms).

I used the following code (https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries) with and without babel package and I came across aforementioned problems. Could anybody help me please? Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are using a tex editor on your own machine, ie not an online editor, then dl the package [tracklang](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/tracklang?lang=en) and run the necessary files to exctract the `.sty` file. Save the files in the folder with the processed document being worked on. If other `.sty` files are needed search everyone's friend Google for them and save them in in the same manor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: MiKTeX + TexMaker

Comment: MikTeX packages `tracklang`. Do not install it manually. If it is not installed already, use MikTeX's package manager to install it. @Leucippus Sorry, but that is not the best advice. Both TeX Live and MikTeX include `tracklang`.

Comment: I recommend passing your language option (e.g. `english`) to the document class (e.g. `\documentclass[english]{article}`. Better still, specify the kind of English if it is English you want. This way the correct settings can be picked by language-aware packages and not just `babel`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is solved with an update of the TeX distribution